# Why does min() not return the actual minimum value?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the minimum value in a list of numerical values in a table using the function min() in R, but I've noticed that it sometimes doesn't return the actual lowest numerical value.

For instance, if the list consisted of 7.760, 12.015, 13.043, and 70.789, if I did min(list), it would return 12.015 as the minimum value and not 7.760. I noticed by just manually sorting the table of values from lowest to highest using the arrows at the top of the column in the table, it would return the order of 12.015, 13.043, 7.760, 70.789 as if ranking the values by the first digit instead of the number as a whole.

Is there a way to fix it or a different function to use in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your numbers are actually character strings

```r
vec <- c(7.760, 12.015, 13.043, 70.789)

min(vec)
# [1] 7.76

vec <- as.character(vec)
min(vec)
# [1] "12.015"
```

Simply convert them to `numeric` with `as.numeric(vec)`, then `min()` will behave as expected

Comment: i tried as.numeric(list) but it still returned 12.015 as the minimum

Comment: @tamcle What do you get if you run `min(c(7.760, 12.015, 13.043, 70.789))` you should see `7.76`. Can you edit your question to include the exact data structure you're working with (you can get this with `dput(your_data)` (e.g. `dput(list)` in your case). It sounds like the data you are providing to `min()` is of character class

Comment: hm maybe I oversimplified my issue when i wrote it in my post, but basically my data is a column in a table, so let's say it's table$1. I did min(table$1) and it would return 12.015. I also tried table$1->list to take it out of the table, then did min(as.numeric(list)) but it still returned 12.015

Comment: I see. Try first converting the data in the table to `numeric` with `table$1 <- as.numeric(table$1)`. Then try `min(table$1)`

Comment: do you happen to know how to select all the values in a column except for the first row in a table? the value in the first row isn't a numeric so i need to exclude it

Comment: `table$1[2:nrow(table)]`

Comment: @tamcle if a numeric column has *even just one* character value in it, the whole column will become character.

Comment: @tamcle in R, `data.frame` columns can only have one class. If there's anything non-numeric in a column, the column cannot be `numeric`